# Is my computer burning out? Red dots on the screen

Tags: display

On the web, I was browsing and some red dots faintly appeared when I looked at the screen from a different angle. I went in a text editor to see if it was the web page, but the dots  were still there. Next day (now) they are still here - I wanted to know if the screen could've been damaged permanently or temporarily because I think it's burned, seeing as the computer was on for a few hours, count dinner in between!

Comment: Are the "red dots" on the actual screen itself, or does it look like they are pixels (the difference doesn't sound like much, but you should be able to see blocks if it's pixels)?  Is this a laptop or desktop?  If it is a desktop, try the screen with another computer (friend, family, etc.)  Also test the desktop with another display (tv, etc.).  It could be artifacting from a bad graphics chip potentially.

Comment: What kind of screen LCD? Are the red dots very small like one pixel each?

Comment: You could have a few dead or stuck sub-pixels.  Each screen pixel is made from three sub-pixels, each for a primary color.  If the green and blue sub-pixels are dead, all you see is red.  But in this case, you should see red only when that pixel is illuminated; if that area of the screen is dark, it should be dark, also.  If the red sub-pixel is stuck on, you should see a red dot even when that portion of the screen is dark.

Answer (score 3):

Are the dots always in the same place or do they move around?  Is it a laptop or a desktop with a separate screen? It's most likely not the whole computer that's damaged. In order of most likely problem If it's a separate monitor, I would say that the problem could be.

1. Monitor Cable - Most monitors have replaceable cables. Try just removing and plugging the cable back in, or try a new cable if this doesn't work.
2. Monitor - Try a different monitor if reconnecting the monitor cable or getting a new cable doesn't work.
3. Video card - Try using a different video card, possibly switching to your on board video card if you are currently using a PCIe video card.  Or try a different output on the same video card.  Video cards can be easily replaced, but they can get expensive.

Comment: as a note if it was a issue of the video card and artifacts from a ram or ram screen buffer, and/or caused by overheating, or even power problems, they often will not clear up until the computer re-initilises the video card, which is done at post.  So a reboot or even a power off may be nessisary.  This is important only when the original problem (say overheated ram) is solved or changed, but the artifacts do not depart.  There is one type of artifacting that will not clear up, even if the whole original problem no longer exists, until re-init.